# Understanding with julia dataframes indexing

Tags: dataframe, indexing, julia, any

I am learning julia and i've just found this line:

```
if(any(mach_df[start_slot:(start_slot + task_setup_time), Symbol(machine)].== 0))
```

What does it mean?, I know any is a function that returns true if every value of the parameter is true but I just can't understand what is inside the brakets.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us work inside out:

- `mach_df[start_slot:(start_slot + task_setup_time), Symbol(machine)]` selects you rows from the range `start_slot:(start_slot + task_setup_time)` and column named `Symbol(machine)` (`Symbol` is most likely not needed, but I would need to see your source code to tell you exacly); as a result you get a vector.
- `mach_df[start_slot:(start_slot + task_setup_time), Symbol(machine)] .== 0` gives you another vector that has `true` if the value in the LHS vector is `0`.
- the `any` part will return true if any of the values in the vector produced above is `true`.

A more advanced (and efficient) way to write it would be:

```
any(==(0), @view mach_df[start_slot:(start_slot + task_setup_time), Symbol(machine)])
```

but I am not sure if you need performance in your use case.

Comment: Thanks a lot, so this line: mach_df = data_set["machines_availability"][:, [Symbol(machine)]], defines a mach_df as the machine column from data_set["machines_availability"], right? (data_set is a dict)

Comment: Yes `[:, [Symbol(machine)]]` creates a data frame (not a vector as in your original question as column selector is wrapped in `[`, `]`) with one column and picking all rows as you use `:` as row selector. Normally this operation would be written as `select(data_set["machines_availability"], Symbol(machine))`.